# Let $G$ be a domain and $f$ be holomorphic in $G$. Show that, if $|f|^2$ is harmonic in $G$, then $f$ is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis

**Complex Analysis**

Let $G$ be a domain and $f$ be holomorphic in $G$. Show that, if $|f|^2$ is harmonic in $G$, then $f$ is constant.

My attempt at a solution so far:

Write $|f|^2=|u+iv|^2=u^2+v^2$

If $|f|^2$ is harmonic, then $\nabla^2|f|^2=$$ \frac{∂^2|f|^2 }{∂x∂x}+\frac{∂^2|f|^2 }{∂y∂y}=0$

Expanding on this:

$$\frac{∂^2|f|^2 }{∂x∂x}+\frac{∂^2|f|^2 }{∂y∂y}=\frac{∂^2 }{∂x∂x}(u^2+v^2)+\frac{∂^2 }{∂y∂y}(u^2+v^2)=\frac{∂ }{∂x}(2u\frac{∂u }{∂x}+2v\frac{∂v }{∂x})+\frac{∂ }{∂y}(2u\frac{∂u }{∂y}+2v\frac{∂v }{∂y})=(2\frac{∂u }{∂x}\frac{∂u }{∂x}+2u\frac{∂^2u }{∂x∂x}+2\frac{∂v }{∂x}\frac{∂v }{∂x}+2v\frac{∂^2v }{∂x∂x})+(2\frac{∂u }{∂y}\frac{∂u }{∂y}+2u\frac{∂^2u }{∂y∂y}+2\frac{∂v }{∂y}\frac{∂v }{∂y}+2v\frac{∂^2v }{∂y∂y})=0$$$($take this as equation $(1))$

At this point I'm unsure (even more), but some factoring and rearrangement is certainly possible.
Does this approach lead anywhere? Somewhere down the line I would need $$\frac{∂u }{∂x}=\frac{∂u }{∂y}=\frac{∂v }{∂x}=\frac{∂v }{∂y}=0$$ for $f$ to be constant. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried the Average Value Theorem?

Comment: At the moment, you haven't used the fact that $f$ is holomorphic.

Comment: For holomorphic $f$: $\nabla^2 \lvert f \rvert^2 = 4 \lvert f’ \rvert^2$. [Wirthinger derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives) are a convenient tool to show this.

Comment: Note that $\nabla^2 u = \nabla^2 v = 0$ because $u$ and $v$ are harmonic. That simplifies your expression considerably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expansion $(1)$ can be written in the form
$$u_x^2+v_x^2+u_y^2+v_y^2+u(u_{xx}+u_{yy})+v(v_{xx}+v_{yy})=0\tag2$$
Given that $f=u+iv$ be holomorphic, so it satisfies Cauchy-Riemann equation and also the real and imaginary parts of the holomorphic function $f$ i.e., $u$ and $v$ are harmonic. Therefore
$$u_x=v_y~,~~~~~u_y=-v_x~,~~~~~\text{and}~~~~u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0~,~~~~~v_{xx}+v_{yy}=0~.$$
Hence from $(2)$ we have$$u_x^2+v_x^2+u_y^2+v_y^2=0$$
$$\implies u_x=v_x=u_y=v_y=0$$
$$\implies u~~\text{and}~~v~~\text{are constants.}$$
Therefore $~f~$ is constant.